# Best practive to keeping API keys from being commited?

Tags: c#, security, api

I am working on a c# program that retrieves information from a webservice and it uses an API key for authentication.

Currently I hardcoded this value in my program, but since I would like to keep the code in a public github repository I have to remove this by hand before committing it.

What is a more automated way of preventing me from accidentally committing with the API key still in the code?

I was thinking of creating a script that adds the secrets in using pre/post-build command execute options in Visual Studio. This way I never have to keep the API key in the code and it will be removed after building so committing it by accident will never happen.

Comment: you could put the API key into an encrypted config file and exclude that file from the repository...

Comment: @Yahia i had that thought too, but then would probably need to include something similar to a -dist file so that someone else who checks out the code would know how to set it up.

Comment: I understand and don't see a problem: you could just checkin an empty/sample file AND I regard it good practice if you put into the repository some sort of readme or whatever with the project describing the basics relevant to the project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [configuration file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or the [Windows Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx).

I'd also recommend encrypting it, on Windows you can use the Data Protection API (DPAPI). .Net 2.0+ has a class call [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) that's very simple to use. This way if you do commit your configuration the key is still encrypted and will only work on your machine or even for your user on that machine depending on how you scope your data protection. You'll want to make some way for people to enter in a key to use on their machines though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your web.config and set up [web config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx) to change it dynamically when you build the project by selecting the appropriate configuration (debug, release etc). You can use this to replace the key with a dummy value.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that this is a desktop application.